# MODIS temperature and NDVI data?

Tags: data, remote-sensing, modis, ndvi

hope anyone could give me some hints here. I tried to download free MODIS data from their page(resolution 500m, 1km). Im interested in NDVI and temperature data. But when i load the hdf files into my project file I just get weird layers :/.  [image: MODIS temperature layers in ArcGIS] This for example should be the temperature layer, but that's nothing I can work with. You have a clue if these are the right files, or if not, if there are better ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the NDVI you can use the product modis MOD13Q1 and for the supercial temperature MOD11A2, the arhivos in HDF format of the products other complementary products I recommend you to check the respective guides

[MOD13Q1](https://vip.arizona.edu/documents/MODIS/MODIS_VI_UsersGuide_01_2012.pdf)

[MOD11A2](http://www.icess.ucsb.edu/modis/LstUsrGuide/MODIS_LST_products_Users_guide_C5.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

These values are scaled Kelvin. You can see in the [MODIS website](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod11c3) detailed specification about the MOD11C3 data
[image]

If you multiply the raster by 0.02 you should get the values in Kelvin

Answer (score 1):

Well, MODIS MCD43A4 data can be found via [landviewer](https://eos.com/landviewer) and you may analyze any of the images with ease by applying NDVI index or create any other index via built-in calculator. However, an option to collect MODIS temperature data is expected to be added soon.
An example of such data can be found [here](https://eos.com/landviewer/?lat=48.24114&lng=6.26770&z=8&preset=passiveLowSensors&side=R&slider-id=LV-TUNE-NDNB-NC5B-MjAx-OTA5-Mi5o-MTh2-MDQu-MDA2-LjIw-MTkx-MDEw-MzEw-MjA%3D&slider-b=NIR,Red&slider-expression=(B02-B01)%2F(B02%2BB01)&slider-anti&id=LV-TUNE-NDNB-NC5B-MjAx-OTA5-Mi5o-MTh2-MDQu-MDA2-LjIw-MTkx-MDEw-MzEw-MjA%3D&b=Red,Green,Blue&anti).

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".